# Local.xml file code to remove "Disc Coupon" & “Shipping/Tax” Blocks in Magento 1.9 not working?

Tags: shopping-cart

I have created a **local.xml** file in folder:

**/app/design/frontend/default/MAG090172/layout**

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<layout> 
<checkout_cart_index> 
   <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping" /> 
</checkout_cart_index> 
<checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="checkout.cart">
                <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

*** Unfortunately, it's NOT removed the 2 blocks from Shopping Cart Page .

Is the file in correct folder ? Is syntax of code correct ?

Pls help.

Comment: show your local.xml file

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record, a year late, without the reference name this worked for me

```
<checkout_cart_index>  
        <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>       
</checkout_cart_index>
```

I think this is because the cart is not in the normal body structure and has its own references

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
            <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: -still NOT working with your code.  Even cleared all caches.

Comment: paste your xml file code

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <!-- Removes estimate shipping and cost on cart page -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="checkout.cart">
                <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
                <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
<layout>

Comment: Snapshot link:  http://s30.postimg.org/fy2fhwbwh/cpanel.png

Comment: its is not layout.xml it should be local.xml.check spelling

Comment: < Ok - i have renamed file to local.xml  > << Should code layout inside code also change to local ?? I have changed that too....New code:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<local>
    <checkout_cart_index>
        <!-- Removes estimate shipping and cost on cart page -->
        <reference name="content">
            <block name="checkout.cart">
                <remove name="checkout.cart.shipping"/>
                <remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </checkout_cart_index>
<local>
 STILL NOT WORKING

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/4lgbti07p/

Comment: please paste myanswer as it is in the local.xml file without changing any thing.

Comment: why you are chainging <local> tag in the my answer

Comment: Ok - i have changed it back to <layout> tag, but still NOT working.   Even after clearing all Caches...

Comment: I simply copied & pasted your code & renamed file to local.xml

Comment: Pradeep > Thanks for your patience.  I have managed to remove the blocks using solution from link: http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/how-to-remove-discount-code-block-from-magento/

Answer (score 0):

From `\Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateXml()`:

There is not much preference where to place the *remove* element, as long as it is part of the update, within the XML generation all *remove* elements regardless where in the document count (`//remove`).

If the *remove* element does not have a *name* attribute, it's ignored.

If you inject xpath improperly via that *name* attribute string value, the *remove* element would be ignored. This is not the case in your question.

Next to *block* elements, also *reference* elements are checked for the name. Here an improper xpath injection would *not* ignore the *remove* element.

All matching nodes (`(//block|//reference)[@name='<name>']`) not having yet an *ignore* attribute and not explicitly allowed via their *acl* attribute will get the *ignore* attribute set to the string value "`1`".

To summarize:

Either the *block* and *reference* elements you name with your *remove* elements aren't defined in the update XML so far (your module must depend on the module which blocks you name here) *or* the *block*  and *reference* elements you're referring to can't be removed (e.g. they have the *ignore* attribute already set to a non-true value).  Another possibility is that the blocks you're removing have been already generated (`\Mage_Core_Model_Layout::generateBlocks()`), then it's too late to remove them. Most likely the first or the last is the case.

What you describe can also be the issue that the update handle isn't in use.

You can quickly troubleshoot these issues by making use of xpath injection from within the layout file. If a layout file has "grip", the following XML document will disable all blocks and references that can be ignored:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="'='"/>
    </default>
</layout>
```

With this little piece of code you can first of all test if the file is in use. If the file is in use (has grip) and as it contains the default handle, it will remove all blocks, so you see a blank page.

Then you can change `<default>` to the handle you'd like to test. If the handle still has grip, you will again see the blank page.

So the final test then is to change the name to the name of the block you'd like to remove. If it isn't removed, then the name of the block is wrong and/or you're removing it before it was in there.